# Socket seems to closing between button presses, how do I keep it open? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've written a small proof of concept bit of code that is supposed to do the following:

1. Pressing button 1 opens socket to server and passes authentication details and collects server response for display. (This works 100%, auth is successful.)
2. Pressing button 2 is supposed to send the command requesting the server status, this is the part that does not work.  The only response I can get back from the server is "waiting to authenticate" despite me successfully doing so by pressing button 1.
   It appears that the socket is closing after the initial button 1 press so is ignoring the button 2 code and is instead waiting for authentication again.

Question:How do I open a socket with button 1, then fire other commands at the server with button 2.

I have tried `s.setKeepAlive(true);` and `s.setSoTimeout(60000);` and also putting the socket method in a thread but no joy.

My Controller.java (watching for button 1 and 2 presses)

```
public class Controller {

@FXML public Button auth;
@FXML public Button status;


public void balls(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    (new Thread(new helloRunnable())).start();
}

public void balls2(javafx.event.ActionEvent event)throws IOException {

    sample.Main.status();
}
}//end class
```

My helloRunnable.Java (works perfectly)

```
public class helloRunnable implements Runnable {

public void run() {

    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.16.230", 63333);
        s.setKeepAlive(true);
        s.setSoTimeout(60000);

        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader bufRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        p.println("{\"method\":\"authentication\",\"server_password\":\"g4t3w4y1\"}");

        String response = bufRd.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);

        p.println("");
        response = bufRd.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);

    } //end try block
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } //end catch

 }//end runnable
}//end class
```

My Main.Java (this is waiting for authentication again as it appears socket reset/closed)

```
public class Main extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void status() throws IOException{

    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.16.230", 63333);

    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader bufRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    p.println("");
    p.println("{ \"method\":\"get_server_status\" }");

    String response = bufRd.readLine();
    //Object obj = JSONValue.parse(response);
    //JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    //String reply = (String) jsonObject.get("reply");
    //System.out.println("Reply: " + reply + "\n");

    System.out.println(response);
 }
}//end main class
```

I have tried all kinds of fixes found here and other places but can't seem to fix it.  Please point me in right direction.  It's frustrating as the CLi based version of this this which is much larger in scope works perfectly.  I authenticate and the socket just stays open.  I can fire different commands at the server all day.

Anyway thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Nothing is closing, which is itself a bug, but you keep creating *new* sockets, which is the problem.

Comment: You need to go global with your runnable.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "global" please?  How?  Its already public.

Comment: You just need to retain a reference to the socket or (probably better) an object that has a reference to the socket. That way you can use the same socket from both event handlers (and it will also give you a way to close the socket when you close the application).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it asks again for authentication, since you create a new socket on every run
instead you want to create the socket once (or at least for a certain amount of time) and re-use it on every run... so.. you need to store your socket /and configure it

Comment: Thanks i'm now on the right track, one thing though I only want to open the socket on the button 1 press, but I'm not sure how to call whatever from within an "action event" handler and have it available to the other methods in my controller and main.java.  I can create the store the socket no probs if I call the creation method at the class level, but obviously this is not waiting for me to press a "connect" button.  Any hints please?

Comment: merge it with the answer of Sedrick and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant by going global. You should do something like this.

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML public Button auth;
    @FXML public Button status;

    // go back and capitalize your class name
    HelloRunnable helloRunnable = new HelloRunnable();//Now the scope of this is the whole class and not just within the Button's handler. I am not sure if this code is 100% correct, but the idea is to widen the Runnable's scope.

    public void balls(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        (new Thread(helloRunnable)).start();//Now start your runnable
    }

    public void balls2(javafx.event.ActionEvent event)throws IOException {

        sample.Main.status();
    }
}//end
```

Comment: No need to change the runnable to store the stocket? Since now the socket is still created everytime `(new Thread(helloRunnable)).start();` is invoked, isn't it?

Comment: This is not meant to fix the OP's problem. It's more to show what I meant by `Global Variable`. I have no idea if the code is going to run like the OP expects. That's why I put a disclaimer in the code.

Comment: I have never had to write a program using `Sockets`, so I am not familiar with the `API`. I personally would disable the `Button` after a connection is made.